# How do I apply a Blend4Web module similar to the plane flight preview?

Tags: opengl, blend4web

I am trying to make a load screen to fit my scene.

This has a custom load screen to fit the scene:
https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/island/

This is the API:
https://www.blend4web.com/api_doc/module-preloader.html

But I can't find how to apply or use the API. How do I apply a Blend4Web module?

Comment: I don't have my computer in front of me to play around with this at the moment (on my iPhone now), but looking at the documentation I have an idea of where you could start looking: inside preloader.js there is some CSS that appears to define the appearance of the preloader.

Comment: Here's what I've learned... within the SDK the files/folders you'll probably want to examine are: (1) */src/addons/preloader.js* (2) */blender/flight_over_island* (3) */apps_dev/flight/ (4) /deploy/apps/flight/* (5) */deploy/assets/flight_over_island/flight_over_island.json* When you make your project I would recommend doing so using the Project Manager, and creating it as a Bundled Project, because that will simplify your file structure. The .html file references the .js and .css files. The .js file references the .json file. You might consider asking this over at www.blend4web.com/en/forums/

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the source files of the Island demo you mentioned.

https://github.com/TriumphLLC/Blend4Web/tree/master/apps_dev/flight

Search for **create_advanced_preloader** in the **flight.js** file.